# Different versions of pages/articles in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am using Drupal7 to set up a website, and want to create different versions of pages or articles, pretty much like the localization support built into Drupal. For example a page called 'Info' is currently available in two Versions:

- German
- English

What I want:

- German

  - VersionA
  - VersionB
- English

  - VersionA
  - VersionB

Then, a session variable or whatever would determine which version is presented to the user, in which language.

I already created a taxonomy field in my content type 'Basic Page', but the locale-module only offers languages, of course...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using [Views](http://drupla.org/project/views). Go to `?q=admin/structure/views/add` and create a new view of type `Content revisions`.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about how you this would implement my needs... I thought revisions just version an item over time? How can I have two(or more) revisions in parallel, all representing a latest state?

Comment: Addition: what I actually want is e.g. three pages, with three different tags of a 'tag-type', which are kind of connected meaning representing the same page, just like the languages moduel does...

Comment: not exactly what I wanted, but your answer pushed me on the (imo) best solution: I created a content-view, and selected single pages using two contextual filters: one for the category, and one for the page title.